# Disable Component in Java GUI w/o Graying it Out

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jcomponent

I'm currently working on a java project that allows a user to play tic-tac-toe against the program. I want to disable the squares that have already been clicked. I was wondering if there is any way to disable the components (JButtons) without graying them out, like what `component.setEnabled(false)` does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Rather than disabling the button, you could create a boolean variable to keep track whether the button is enabled or disabled. Then, when the button is clicked, check the boolean variable then run the function.

For example:

```
private boolean buttonEnabled = true;
```

.

```
buttonEnabled = false;
```

.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
   if (buttonEnabled){
      //what the button does
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom look and feel on your JButton by overriding parts of the UI and Paint Methods. That way when you disable the button, it looks the same, just it will not do anything.

For example, the following code produces this.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DisableButtonExample extends JFrame {

    public DisableButtonExample() {
        super("Disabled Button Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        setUp();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setUp() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;

        JLabel standardButtons = new JLabel("Standard Buttons", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        mainPanel.add(standardButtons, gc);

        JLabel customButtons = new JLabel("Custom Buttons", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        mainPanel.add(customButtons, gc);

        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;

        JButton standardEnabled = new JButton("Standard Enabled Button");
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(standardEnabled, gc);

        JButton standardDisabled = new JButton("Standard Disabled Button");
        standardDisabled.setEnabled(false);
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(standardDisabled, gc);

        JButton customEnabled = new CustomButton("Custom Enabled Button");
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(customEnabled, gc);

        JButton customDisabled = new CustomButton("Custom Disabled Button");
        customDisabled.setEnabled(false);
        gc.gridx = 3;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(customDisabled, gc);

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new DisableButtonExample());
    }

    private class CustomButton extends JButton {
        private boolean mousePressed = false;
        private CustomButtonUI ui = new CustomButtonUI();

        //Values from UIManager.get("Button.gradient")
        private Color fontColor = Color.BLACK;
        private Color c1 = new Color(221, 232, 243);
        private Color c2 = Color.WHITE;
        private Color c3 = new Color(184, 207, 229);

        public CustomButton(String textToDisplay) {
            super(textToDisplay);

            //Make it so we can use our own background colour when the button is disabled
            setContentAreaFilled(false);

            //Set custom UI so text is same colour when button is disabled
            ui = new CustomButtonUI();
            setUI(ui);

            //Set the font colour
            setForeground(fontColor);

            //A way to find out when the mouse is pressed
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePressed = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePressed = false;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if(!mousePressed || !isEnabled()) {
                //Best guess at recreating the standard look of a JButton
                GradientPaint grad1 = new GradientPaint(0, (getHeight() * 3) / 10, c2, 0, (getHeight() * 8) / 10, c1, true);
                g2.setPaint(grad1);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                GradientPaint grad2 = new GradientPaint(0, (getHeight() * 5) / 10, new Color(c3.getRed(), c3.getGreen(), c3.getBlue(), 0), 0, getHeight(), c3);
                g2.setPaint(grad2);
            } else if(mousePressed && isEnabled()) {
                g2.setPaint(c3);
            }
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        //Override so if you change text colour, it gets updated in the disabled state of the button
        @Override
        public void setForeground(Color fg) {
            if(ui != null) {
                ui.setFontColour(fg);
            }
            super.setForeground(fg);
        }

        //UI that controls the disabled state font colour
        private class CustomButtonUI extends MetalButtonUI  {
            private Color fontColor = Color.BLACK;

            public void setFontColour(Color fontColor) {
                this.fontColor = fontColor;
            }

            @Override
            public Color getDisabledTextColor() {
                return fontColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```